# Trying to parse a "txt" file to a dictionary, in the last line it always return a "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"

Tags: python, string, dictionary

```
tabela={}

def initiate():
    """initiate the file"""
    with open("file.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            (key, val) = line.split(":")
            tabela[key] = int(val)
initiate()
```

"file.txt"

```
test1:123
test2:456
test3:789
test4:951
test5:357
```

Comment: Make sure the last line of the file doesn't have a newline. Or verify that `line` contains a `':'`. Example: `if ':' in line: ....`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to add some check conditions like:

```py
def initiate():
    """initiate the file"""
    with open("file.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line and ":" in line:    # <= check conditions
                (key, val) = line.split(":")
                tabela[key] = int(val)
```